# PYTHON PIL: remove everything from image except text (based on pixel color)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I have some images that have subtitle/text on them and i want to remove everything from picture but let clear text on that,(most important is that text need to be clear and good so any ocr program can read it).

-In original image(1.png) text should be white  but that doesnt mean it is RGB:255,255,255 so it vary from pixel to pixel. so this is problem that i cant find a way to get just text.

Maybe i need to convert rgb to something different , maybe any value with percentage or idk

> i tried with below code to convert image  1.png to 2.png and here are
> the results but they are not good enought

1.png:
[image]

2.png
[image]

```
RGB_min=[180,180,180]
RGB_max=[245,245,245]

def level(img):
    copy = img.copy()
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            pxl = list(copy.getpixel((x, y)))
            # if pxl[0] < 220 and pxl[1] < 220: 
            if (pxl[0] < RGB_min[0] and pxl[1] < RGB_min[1]  ) or (pxl[0] > RGB_max[0] or pxl[1] >RGB_max[1]) : 
                pxl[0] = 255
                pxl[1] = 255
                pxl[2] = 255
            else:
                pxl[0] = 0
                pxl[1] = 0
                pxl[2] = 0
                
            copy.putpixel((x, y), tuple(pxl))
    return copy

image = Image.open('1.png')
leveled = level(image)
leveled.save('2.png')
```

here u can see how pixels are in text if you zoom in.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try looking for bright values in [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colourspace like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Load image and convert to HSV
im = Image.open('t6FkL.png').convert('HSV')

# Split channels, just retaining the Value channel
_, _, V = im.split()

# Select pixels where V>220
res = V.point(lambda p: p > 220 and 255)
res.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

Here is a maybe more intuitive way of writing the `point()` function to deal with compound logic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Build a linear gradient 0..255
im = Image.linear_gradient('L')

# Save how it looks initially just for debug
im.save('DEBUG-start.png')

# Make all pixels between 180..220 black, leaving others as they were
res = im.point(lambda p: 0 if p>180 and p<220 else p)

# Save result
res.save('result.png')
```

Here is the start image:

[image]

And the processed image:

[image]

Comment: Which line causes that error please?

Comment: fixed, that was different error. 
 Can u comment the logic u use so me and other will better understeand.  what 220 and 255 mean

Comment: It just means that if a pixel's brightness value is greater than 220, the pixel will become white (255) and if it is lower or equal to 220, it will become black. It is described here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#point-operations

Comment: in HSV  V should be percentage from 0 to 100 right?  what 220 is percentage or like RGB

Comment: It’s 8-bit, so the range is 0..255

Comment: how can we  put a range example  if p > 220  and p < 240

Comment: I have added an example with a compound condition in the `point()` function so you can see how to do more complicated tests. Please have another look.